# A way to use GPU hardware in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, python, matlab

I know that theano is a python library for using gpu hardware and make effective implementations. Is there any such library or a way to do the same in matlab?

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! However, I think your question fits better to stack overflow, so I voted to migrate it there.

Comment: @cbeleites "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Unfortunately this question falls between forums here, in my view.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request to name code.

Comment: @NickCox: Fair enough & I agree, but my first thought was that it is even less about statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Is [CudaMat](http://www.nanoimaging.de/CudaMat/) what you're looking for?

Nowadays, also Matlab's Parallel Computing Toolbox enables GPU use: see  http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html